# Run method async after rendering a page grails 3.1

Tags: grails, asynchronous, groovy, promise

In My Grails service, I would like to render a page while promise or some methods are running asynchronously. I tried different things from the documentation 
https://docs.grails.org/3.1.10/guide/async.html. 
While debugging I saw that return render runs before the promise, however in front end still it doesn't render anything until promise finishes running. 
I tried to use promise and thread. None of the things I listed worked as I wanted. 
I even copied saveOrder to copyOrder, thought maybe promise stops the result from rendering. Still didn't work.

```
def save(Order order) {   
    def saveorder = orderService.saveOrder(order, user.id)
    def copyOrder=new AppreciationOrder();
    InvokerHelper.setProperties(copyOrder, saveorder.properties)

    response.status = 201
    Promise p = task {
        checkService.checkForDuplicate(saveorder)
        notificationService.newOrder(saveorder)
    }
    p.onComplete { result ->
        println "Promise returned $result"
    }
    return render(view: "/controllers/order/order/_show", model: [order: copyOrder])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting rather than render e.g. the following assumes your save action is from Order domain:

```
redirect( action: 'show', params: [order: copyOrder] )
```

You may have to play with the params above e.g. if your show action expects an ID you could do:

```
redirect( action: 'show', id: copyOrder.id )
```

I think your async code would be better placed in a service, you can add an onError clause too e.g.

```
p.onError { Exception err ->
    println "Error - $err"
}
```

Comment: tried everything you recommended and it still waits.